# Unrecognized content encoding type with fromJSON function in R

Tags: r, json

I get the following error with `fromJSON()` function from the `jsonlite` package in R:

```
> jsonlite::fromJSON(url)
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
  Unrecognized content encoding type. libcurl understands identity content encodings.
```

where `url` is

```
https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=30278479+30196285+30170405&retmode=json
```

Any idea how to resolve that is appreciated.

Comment: Worked for me with win10, R-3.5.1, jsonlite-1.5, curl-3.2. I suspect this is more likely a `libcurl` problem, not a `jsonlite` problem.

Comment: @r2evans It seems there was an issue with `libcurl` library that comes with linuxbrew package manager.

Comment: Great, so you solved your problem! If it's nontrivial, it might be good to post an answer and accept it.